# WinRT GridView crashes

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

When displaying **more than 13** (12 or less works fine) large images (3264x2448) scaled down into 320x180 image items - GridView crashes with unmanaged exception: Unhandled exception at 0x7583A862 (combase.dll).

Xaml:

```
<GridView x:Name="ImagesGridView" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Source}" Height="180" Width="320" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Loading code:

```
private static async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImage(StorageFile file)
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        var stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

        stream.CloneStream();
        return bitmapImage;

    }

    public async void GetPictures()
    {
        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, new[] { ".png", ".jpg" });
        var picturesQuery = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions).GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var pictureFile in picturesQuery)
        {
            var bitmap = await LoadImage(pictureFile);
            var img = new Image { Source = bitmap };
            ImagesGridView.Items.Add(img);
        }
    }
```

Crash happens not on loading image, but after all loading successful and app should show images in GridView. Also I'm using copy of same image to be sure that all images are identical.

To me it seems common to load large images in app, so maybe I'm doing something really wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your image controls are only 320x180 you are loading the images at full resolution, so you are attempting to feed 3264x2448x4(bytes per pixel)x13 =~400MB of textures into your video card which might be a bit of a stretch.

Try using `StorageFile.GetThumbnailAsync()` to load the images, eg.

```
private static async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImageAsync(StorageFile pictureFile)
{
    using (var stream = await pictureFile.GetThumbnailAsync(
        ThumbnailMode.SingleItem,
        320,
        ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail))
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will mark this as an answer, but while you here - I have related question: what about images from web? I'm only testing on local images but ultimately I will need to fetch large images (maybe not as large but in higher numbers) from web and I cant get thumbnails of them (I guess), should I download large image then resize it for grid manually and hold originals in the memory? Since it seems waste of bandwidth to download them twice (for grid and for image zoom-in).

Comment: That's a separate question and it has many answers depending on what your scenario is. 1. You should get thumbnails off the web for large numbers of images. 2. You could get full versions, save them locally and then load thumbnails off of these (`GetThumbnailAsync()` will generate a new thumbnail for you). 3. You could use some caching for the files you download - either depend on the web stack or build your own cache. 4. You should make sure your list control uses virtualization for what it displays which it does by default, but can stop if you change `ItemsPanel` template.